# Running AOSP make tests

Tags: android, testing, android-source

AOSP includes a large number of tests that seem like they can be used to test system functionality. These seem like they would be very useful at a deeper level than CTS. If you execute "make tests" it will generate a .zip file containing a large number of apks from various tests included in aosp, as well as some binaries included in things folders like "nativebenchmark", "nativestresstest", etc.

I can install and run the apk tests manually, but I don't know how to run the binary tests. Further more, the zip file contains various xml files that seem describe all the coverage targets and text definitions. The xml files seem like they would be useful for a testing tool of some sort but I can't find anything that specifically references this package. There is also the runtest.py script but it doesn't have anything to do with this package that can be generated.

I am interested to know what the intended way is to run these tests and the purpose of this auto-generated package? Is this just a deprecated method of testing? If so, does anyone know what the official method for system testing is? I.E. What is Google or LGE using to test their products before releasing them? CTS only goes so far, and I can't find any sort of documentation on these system tests.

Answer (score 0):

I ran some of OpenGL related tests.

For the opengl code, they are just arm linux binaries.   They best be run if the JVM is disable.   Otherwise, they interfere with the standard GUI output.   I just ran them in the adb shell, normally under su as root.